# Splitting and iterative simple regression in r

Tags: r, loops, plyr, linear-regression

I am pretty much new to r and I have a dummy example of a bigger table underneath. I want to split the table based on id (a,b,c,d) and do iterative simple linear regression for every subset:
x is my x variable, and columns 1:6 are y variables, to have an output of each id and each column from 1:6. Also, it would be great if I could output the model p values of the slopes into a new data frame

```
        id x  1  2  3  4  5  6
    1   a 74 18 19 NA 23 29  1
    2   a 77 16 19 17 22 29  2
    3   a 79 16 NA 19 23 29  3
    4   a 81 17 20 18 23 29  4
    5   b 74 19 20 19 23 28 11
    6   b 76 15 19 18 26 28 12
    7   b 79 19 21 20 24 28 NA
    8   b 81 19 21 20 23 28 14
    9   c 68 19 20 20 23 29  8
    10  c 70 17 22 22 27 29  9
    11  c 73 18 22 21 23 29 10
    12  c 75 19 20 19 23 29 11
    13  d 65 18 18 19 22 28  5
    14  d 68 18 NA 18 20 29  6
    15  d 70 18 19 18 23 28  7
    16  d 72 19 17 19 22 28  8
```

I tried to do use plyr package but it didn't work out

```
 regression = NULL
for ( i in 3:ncol(dumm)){

      regression[i] <- dlply(dumm, .(id), function(z) lm(dumm[,i]~dumm$x, z))
}
coefs <- ldply(regression, coef)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Have you looked at `?by()` or `?split()` or `?lapply()` or anything? You should include what you've tried and what specifically you are having difficulty with.

Comment: So you want to regress each of `y1` - `y6` against `x`, for each group? That would be 6 regressions per group. Is that correct? So in this example there would be 24 sets of coefficients??

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Do you only want the p-values?

Comment: Yes, just the p value of the slopes